# Side brace in dfrac

Tags: braces, empheq

So I have this formula

```
\begin{empheq}[right=\empheqrbrace]{align*}
\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{
    \frac{1}{a} % <-- start with this a
}{a}}{a}}{\vdots}}{a}
```

that's rendered in this formula:

[image]

which is nice, but would it be possible to start the brace just a little lower, i.e. begin with the first a; currently it begins on top, i.e. at the number 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a double array; `empheq` is not the right tool.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{c}
\\[-.3\normalbaselineskip]
\left.
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
\\[-1.7\normalbaselineskip]
\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{
    \frac{1}{a} % <-- start with this a
}{a}}{a}}{\vdots}}{a}
\end{array}
\right\rbrace
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

The two empty rows are compensated by the two negative spacings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's a good solution, but uses array.

Comment: @implicit_knowledge And what's wrong with it? Note that this one ensures correct vertical spacing; the other two solution (which are mostly equivalent) don't.

Comment: In my context, the other ones work because I use the formula as a standalone image, so I don't need to use array. But I see that your solution is "more right" than the others. OK; I changed your solution, because it seems it is the correct thing to do in normal context.

Comment: @implicit_knowledge Then try using `\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}` instead of `\documentclass{article}`: you'll be surprised with Bernard's solution.

Answer (score 4):

Add some positive vertical spacing before `empheq` (e.g. `\vspace*{\baselineskip}`) and add the same amount of negative spacing (e.g. `\\[-\baselineskip]`) inside `empheq`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\begin{empheq}[right=\empheqrbrace]{align*}
\\[-\baselineskip]
\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{
    \frac{1}{a} % <-- start with this a
}{a}}{a}}{\vdots}}{a}
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This won't be correctly spaced with respect to the context.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good solution. But Bernard's is even simpler.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution using `\smash` within `empheq`. You may have to make some manual adjustment w.r.t. the above context:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]\medskip
\begin{empheq}[right=\empheqrbrace]{align*}
  \dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{
    \smash[t]{ \frac{1}{a}} % <-- start with this a
    }{a}}{a}}{\vdots}}{a}
\end{empheq}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I also get a different output. The upper part of the brace is exactly vertically in the middle of the number 1.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed in different tentative solutions. I've updated to the correct one, even simpler.

Comment: Yes, without \vphantom this is better and simpler. It's the easiest solution and renders perfectly now. Thanks!

Comment: This has the same defect as karlkoeller's solution: it doesn't space correctly when in context. Try adding `\lipsum*[2]` before the `empheq` environment.

Comment: I does work for me because I use it as a standalone image. But if needed in context, egreg's solution should be taken with \array.

Comment: It may require some manual adjustment for vertical spacing, as explained in my updated answer and example.